# Installing SageMath packages on windows 10 - "cannot run C compiled programs"

Tags: sage

I just did a fresh install of SageMath 8.9 (Windows installer 0.5.1).

I want to use "[The Normaliz backend for polyhedral computations](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/discrete_geometry/sage/geometry/polyhedron/backend_normaliz.html)".

I run the `sage -i pynormaliz` inside `SageMath 8.9 Shell`. It starts acquiring `yasm`, and halts:

```
[yasm-1.3.0.p0] checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/opt/sagemath-8.9/local/var/tmp/sage/build/yasm-1.3.0.p0/src':
[yasm-1.3.0.p0] configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
```

I'm now sure how to proceed.

The config.log seems to indicate the problem is in permissions? We have in console.log:

```
...
configure:3758: ./conftest.exe
./configure: line 3760: ./conftest.exe: Permission denied
configure:3762: $? = 126
configure:3769: error: in `/opt/sagemath-8.9/local/var/tmp/sage/build/yasm-1.3.0.p0/src':
configure:3771: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
```

I do not know how to circumvent this.

Here is the whole config.log

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by yasm configure 1.3.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/opt/sagemath-8.9/local --libdir=/opt/sagemath-8.9/local/lib

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = DESKTOP-R9A6BND
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.0.7(0.338/5/3)
uname -s = CYGWIN_NT-10.0
uname -v = 2019-04-30 18:08

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /opt/sagemath-8.9/build/bin
PATH: /opt/sagemath-8.9/src/bin
PATH: /opt/sagemath-8.9/local/bin
PATH: /opt/sagemath-8.9/local/lib/R/lib
PATH: /opt/sagemath-8.9/local/lib
PATH: /opt/sagemath-8.9/build/bin
PATH: /opt/sagemath-8.9/src/bin
PATH: /opt/sagemath-8.9/local/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath
PATH: /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath
PATH: /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32
PATH: /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS
PATH: /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem
PATH: /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/ATI Technologies/ATI.ACE/Core-Static
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Live/Shared
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/nodejs
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Brackets/command
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/130/Tools/Binn
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/dotnet
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Xoreax/IncrediBuild
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64
PATH: /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Wolfram Research/WolframScript
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a/runtime/win64
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018a/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Acronis/SnapAPI
PATH: /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Python 3.6
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Users/M/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_131/lib
PATH: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2018.3.4/bin
PATH: /cygdrive/c/MinGW/bin
PATH: /usr/lib/lapack


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2536: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2604: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2615: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2670: result: yes
configure:2821: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2860: result: /usr/bin/mkdir -p
configure:2867: checking for gawk
configure:2883: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2894: result: gawk
configure:2905: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2927: result: yes
configure:2956: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:2973: result: yes
configure:3099: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:3108: result: no
configure:3204: checking for style of include used by make
configure:3232: result: GNU
configure:3303: checking for gcc
configure:3330: result: gcc
configure:3559: checking for C compiler version
configure:3568: gcc --version >&5
gcc (GCC) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3579: $? = 0
configure:3568: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-7.4.0-1.x86_64/src/gcc-7.4.0/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-7.4.0-1.x86_64/src/gcc-7.4.0 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=x86_64-pc-cygwin --host=x86_64-pc-cygwin --target=x86_64-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libcilkrts --enable-libgomp --enable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-libssp --enable-libada --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.4.0 (GCC) 
configure:3579: $? = 0
configure:3568: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3579: $? = 1
configure:3568: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3579: $? = 1
configure:3599: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3621: gcc   -L/opt/sagemath-8.9/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/sagemath-8.9/local/lib  conftest.c  >&5
configure:3625: $? = 0
configure:3673: result: yes
configure:3676: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:3678: result: a.exe
configure:3684: checking for suffix of executables
configure:3691: gcc -o conftest.exe   -L/opt/sagemath-8.9/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/sagemath-8.9/local/lib  conftest.c  >&5
configure:3695: $? = 0
configure:3717: result: .exe
configure:3739: checking whether we are cross compiling
configure:3747: gcc -o conftest.exe   -L/opt/sagemath-8.9/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/sagemath-8.9/local/lib  conftest.c  >&5
configure:3751: $? = 0
configure:3758: ./conftest.exe
./configure: line 3760: ./conftest.exe: Permission denied
configure:3762: $? = 126
configure:3769: error: in `/opt/sagemath-8.9/local/var/tmp/sage/build/yasm-1.3.0.p0/src':
configure:3771: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CCLD_FOR_BUILD_set=
ac_cv_env_CCLD_FOR_BUILD_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_BUILD_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_FOR_BUILD_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=gcc
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_FOR_HOST_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_FOR_HOST_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='-L/opt/sagemath-8.9/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/sagemath-8.9/local/lib '
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_PYTHON_set=
ac_cv_env_PYTHON_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_exeext=.exe
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/usr/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /opt/sagemath-8.9/local/var/tmp/sage/build/yasm-1.3.0.p0/src/config/missing aclocal-1.14'
AMDEPBACKSLASH='\'
AMDEP_FALSE='#'
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='1'
AM_V='$(V)'
AR='ar'
ARCH=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /opt/sagemath-8.9/local/var/tmp/sage/build/yasm-1.3.0.p0/src/config/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /opt/sagemath-8.9/local/var/tmp/sage/build/yasm-1.3.0.p0/src/config/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /opt/sagemath-8.9/local/var/tmp/sage/build/yasm-1.3.0.p0/src/config/missing automake-1.14'
AWK='gawk'
BUILD_MAN_FALSE=''
BUILD_MAN_TRUE=''
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CCLD_FOR_BUILD=''
CC_FOR_BUILD=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CPP_FOR_HOST=''
CYGPATH_W='cygpath -w'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR='.deps'
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT='.exe'
GCC=''
GETTEXT_MACRO_VERSION=''
GMSGFMT=''
GMSGFMT_015=''
GREP=''
HAVE_PYTHON_BINDINGS_FALSE=''
HAVE_PYTHON_BINDINGS_TRUE=''
HAVE_PYTHON_FALSE=''
HAVE_PYTHON_TRUE=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
INTLLIBS=''
INTL_MACOSX_LIBS=''
LDFLAGS='-L/opt/sagemath-8.9/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/sagemath-8.9/local/lib '
LIBICONV=''
LIBINTL=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBICONV=''
LTLIBINTL=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /opt/sagemath-8.9/local/var/tmp/sage/build/yasm-1.3.0.p0/src/config/missing makeinfo'
MKDIR_P='/usr/bin/mkdir -p'
MORE_CFLAGS=''
MSGFMT=''
MSGFMT_015=''
MSGMERGE=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE='yasm'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='bug-yasm@tortall.net'
PACKAGE_NAME='yasm'
PACKAGE_STRING='yasm 1.3.0'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='yasm'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.3.0'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
POSUB=''
PYTHON=''
PYTHON_EXEC_PREFIX=''
PYTHON_INCLUDES=''
PYTHON_PLATFORM=''
PYTHON_PREFIX=''
PYTHON_VERSION=''
RANLIB='ranlib'
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/usr/bin/bash'
STRIP=''
USE_NLS=''
VERSION='1.3.0'
XGETTEXT=''
XGETTEXT_015=''
XGETTEXT_EXTRA_OPTIONS=''
XMLTO=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep='_no'
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias=''
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host=''
host_alias=''
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /opt/sagemath-8.9/local/var/tmp/sage/build/yasm-1.3.0.p0/src/config/install-sh'
libdir='/opt/sagemath-8.9/local/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
pkgpyexecdir=''
pkgpythondir=''
prefix='/opt/sagemath-8.9/local'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
pyexecdir=''
pythondir=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "yasm"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "yasm"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.3.0"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "yasm 1.3.0"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "bug-yasm@tortall.net"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "yasm"
#define VERSION "1.3.0"

configure: exit 1
```

Comment: Sometimes the precompiled versions do not have working compilers, or you have to get them.

Comment: Also, you may want to ask at [ask.sagemath](https://ask.sagemath.org) where you may get a quicker response.

Comment: It appears that the problem is with Sage itself: [Installing packages on windows 10](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/48583/installing-packages-on-windows-10/?answer=48621#post-id-48621).

Comment: Glad you found help there!